# JavaFX| TableView sum of specific column

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a tableview with filters. One is a date range (from, to) and the other is a name filter.
I want to calculate the sum of data in a particular column even when i'm applying filters in real time. How can I achieve this?

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        loadSalesReports(); //saves the data from database in class level arrayList = savedLubesSalesReportsList
        FilteredList<LubesSalesReport> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(savedLubesSalesReportsList), p -> true);
        //DatePicker txtEndDate (max range of date filter)
        txtEndDate.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(pumpData -> {
                    //filters by dates
                if (pumpData.getDate().before(dateTo) || pumpData.getDate().equals(dateTo)) {
                    if (pumpData.getDate().after(dateFrom) || pumpData.getDate().equals(dateFrom)) {
                        //calculate sum here
                        double total = 0;
                        for(LubesSalesReport lsr:tblLubesReport.getItems()){
                            total = total+lsr.getAmount();
                        }
                        txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                        return true; //this filters table by dates but doesn;t calculate new sum after filter
                    }
                }
                return false; 
            });
        });
        SortedList<LubesSalesReport> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tblLubesReport.comparatorProperty());
        //TableView<LubesSalesReport> tblLubesReport;
        tblLubesReport.setItems(sortedData);
        for (int i = 0; i < savedLubesSalesReportsList.size(); i++) {
                  //columns for table
        }
        //displays initial sum for entire table, works as intended
        double total = 0;
        for(LubesSalesReport lsr:tblLubesReport.getItems()){
            total = total+lsr.getAmount();
        }
        txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
```

When I set the end date, my table is filtered, but new sum calculation isn't shown (displays initial one instead). How may I resolve this? I just tried adding the sum in the filter method before they `return`, it's what made sense to me. What am I missing? What should I do? Thanks

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Don't calculate the total in the predicate; the predicate should just define the filtering (i.e. whether or not the item should be included). Add a listener to the filtered list and update the total from that listener.

Comment: @James_D perfect. Thank you. Just starting out with Java and I wasn't aware you could addListener to a list. that's pretty cool. Working perfectly now, thanks. Awesome explanation btw

Comment: That's JavaFX specific, btw; you can't add listeners to a general `java.util.List`, but JavaFX defines an API around "observable" properties and collections (such as `ObservableList` and its subinterfaces). This enables the UI components to observe (or "listen to") the data and stay in sync.

Comment: That's so cool XD lol. Thanks a lot James. How do I mark your comment as the answer?